# Button generated by Javascript unrecognized until right click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Issue: generated button isn't registered on click ~1/20 times.

I'm generating a button :

```
var thebutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
thebutton.setAttribute("id", "mybutton");
thebutton.setAttribute("class", "mybuttonclass");
thebutton.setAttribute("onclick","function()");
thebutton.innerHTML = '<i class="icon info"></i>';
document.getElementById("row").appendChild(thebutton);
```

Which is appended on top an existing button element as a second z-index layer:

```
.mybuttonclass {
  z-index:9999;
}
```

I am also using

```
focusMethod = function getFocus() {           
    document.getElementById("mybutton").focus();
}   

focusMethod();
```

In order to shift the browser selection from the trigger of the generating code (also a button) to `#mybutton` which works as it is highlighted.

Still for some reason, arbitrarily, every few times the button is created, any clicks will not registered to the created button, and in order to fix it and be able to trigger it, i need to right click the page  -- after which the button starts to work.

Is there any way to have the browser rescan the page for elements after I generate the button? Or is there some other issue causing this that I'm missing?

Seems to happen in chrome more often, bootstrap is also run on CSS for the page.

Comment: How do you determine, whenever button click is registered, or not?

Comment: it triggers another function when it's interacted with and the click is registered.